# exacttarget API unstable

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

We are using Apache Axis client to call ExactTarget soap API.

The Java method

> CreateResponseDocument
>   com.exacttarget.PartnerAPIStub.create(CreateRequestDocument arg0)
>   throwsRemoteException

is throwing RemoteException with message “Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).”

We are seeing this since 11/16. This error is intermittent but very frequent. It suggests that exact target endpoint is unstable.

Thanks,

Rishi

Comment: Which endpoint are you using? We've noted that the sandbox endpoint is very unstable and we've given up using it as it frequently times out. If you want to test this in a dev environment I suggest you sign up for a free [developer edition](https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/) which works with production endpoints.

Comment: Have you enabled logging so you can see the actual HTTP request/response when this issue occurs? Do you have the full stack trace?